# Object Attribute Copying Bug - Duplicated values - Can't explain

Tags: javascript, object, debugging, multidimensional-array

I am creating a coordinate grid in JSON for a basic helicopter flight simulator I am working on in Three.js.

I have created the repo here: https://github.com/mpaccione/coordinate_generator

The inputted data is one giant flat array of 60KM^2 Shuttle Radar Topography Data at 60M resolution. Every 600 is a new latitude increment. Due to the output of the SRTM data I needed to create a much more usable grid system that I could access quickly and logically.

My approach was to break it into a 60x60 Grid (1KM Resolution) with a 10x10 Subgrid in each (0.1KM Resolution). Save this multidimensional array system to a JSON file. Then I can segments into memory via Indexed DB and access each grid tile of data directly in the browser in the simulator.

```
[Grid Lat][Grid Long][Subgrid Lat][Subgrid Long]
[0][0][0][0] (Start)
[59][59][9][9] (End)
```

Each Subgrid object has three properties:

```
{
   "latitude":28.15079129,
   "longitude":87.32386969333332,
   "elevation":3805
}
```

Currently the setup to create this final structured JSON file looks like this:

```
function createGrid(data){
    console.log('createGrid');
    const GRID_SIZE = 60;
    const SUBGRID_SIZE = 10;

    let grid = new Array(GRID_SIZE).fill(new Array(GRID_SIZE));

    //LOOP OVER EVERY GRID SQUARE
    for (let j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE; j++){
        for (let i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++){
            // FOR EACH SQUARE IN GRID
            grid[i][j] = new Array(SUBGRID_SIZE).fill(new Array(SUBGRID_SIZE))
            // MAKE SUBGRID
            for (let z = 0; z < SUBGRID_SIZE; z++){
                for (let y = 0; y < SUBGRID_SIZE; y++){
                    // EACH SQUARE IN SUBGRID
                    const offset = ((j * 10) + z) + (600 * ((10 * i) + y))
                    grid[i][j][y][z] = data["results"][offset];
                    console.log(`${i}-${j}-${y}-${z}: Latitude: ${data["results"][offset]["latitude"]} Longitude: ${data["results"][offset]["longitude"]}`) 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    writeToFile(JSON.stringify(grid), `/grid/Grid_Output_${name}_${GRID_SIZE}`, `/grid/Grid_Info_${name}_${GRID_SIZE}`, {"gridSize": GRID_SIZE, "subgridSize": SUBGRID_SIZE}, 'json', function(){
        console.log("Grid File Write Successful");
    });

}
```

So great right? Does what it needs to? NO! I can't figure it out why...

but **the latitude property of the object is the same value for *every single object* however in the console logging it appears correctly.**

I've tried all sorts of things like parsing and stringifying, manually assigning, etc. Perhaps it is some compiler assignment issue in Javascript?

Comment: Don't use `.fill` with non-primitives - use `Array.from` to create the array instead, to create a new array for every iteration. Eg `const grid = Array.from(
  { length: GRID_SIZE },
  () => []
);` (except more nested). When you use `.fill`, you'll be filling the new array with multiple references to the same array in memory, so changing one array item will change all

Comment: Okay I will test using Array.from and see if that works...

Comment: This totally works wow... thank you!